# error in Webconfig "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i keep getting this error in my webconfig dunno why.
im trying to use AD authentication in my asp.net c# website
[image]

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="10"
        loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx">
</forms>
</authentication>

 <authorization>
<deny users="?" />
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>

   <membership defaultProvider="DomainLoginMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
  <add name="DomainLoginMembershipProvider"
       type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
       connectionUsername="username" connectionPassword="password"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you check AD is configured properly and port is accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is self explanatory. I can see clearly from the screen shot that you have included the `authentication` section directly inside the `configuration` node but it should be present inside `system.web` node. So your Web.Config should look like this:-

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" timeout="10"
             loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx">
         </forms>
      </authentication>
 ...Others
    </system.web>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" .....Others
</configuration>
```